# Using MATLAB's symbolic tool to find functional relationships

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I am working with MATLAB's symbolic tools to rearrange some equations to find the functional relationship between the three.

My equations are...

[image: Pi1],
[image: Pi2],
[image: Pi3]

All the terms in the above equations are related by

[image: V] and [image: tau] where dP/dx is constant and my goal is to get an answer in the form [image: f].

This is the start of my code.

```
syms V u v H mu rho dPdx tau % u and v replace V1 and V2
eqn1 = Pi_1 == tau/(rho*V^2);
eqn2 = Pi_2 == (rho*V*H)/mu;
eqn3 = Pi_3 == (dPdx*H)/(rho*V^2);

eqnA = V == (u+v)/2 - H^2/(12*mu)*dPdx;
eqnB = tau == (H/2)*dPdx + mu*(u-v)/2;

A = solve(eqn1,tau);
B = solve(eqn2,V);
C = solve(eqn3,dPdx);

eqnA2 = subs(eqnA,[V,dPdx],[B,subs(C,V,B)]);
eqnB2 = subs(subs(eqnB,dPdx,C),V,B);

eqns = [eqnA2;eqnB2];

S = solve(eqns);
u = S.u;   % V1
v = S.v;   % V2
```

But now if I take that solution for u and v and plug it into eqnB and solve for Pi_1 I get Pi_1 = Pi_1 which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The first logical steps seems to me to substitute `V` and `tau` from `eqnA` and `eqnB` in the first three equations (through something like `eqn1p = subs(eqn1, [lhs(eqnA), lhs(eqnB)], [rhs(eqnA), rhs(rqnB)])`, etc. So now you are left with three equations that can be combined in an infinite number of ways. The question is which two of the seven-odd symbols on the right hand sides of these three equations you *don't want* in the final formula.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused, is lhs and rhs a MATLAB command or is it your own notation?

Comment: They are matlab functions (old mupad); you may find interesting the paragraph about "substitution in equations" in the [subs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) docs page

Comment: I'll take a look thanks.